# Analogue computers

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

Since every continuous variable can be sliced into many discrete values, is there a particular class of problem that can only be solved by an analogue computer?

Comment: A mole contains 602 thousand billion billion molecules and a molecule has a complex, possibly nondeterministic behavior driven by quantum mechanics. So besides a gross statistical description, tracing a single molecule in a glass of water seems out of our reach, though the glass implements it perfectly.